# Wordpress & Nginx with Docker: Static files not loaded

Tags: wordpress, nginx, docker

I'm using Docker to serve my simple WordPress website. A nginx container and a wordpress container. Simple setup:

```
upstream wordpress_english {
  server wordpress_en:80;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name my_domain.com www.my_domain.com;

  location / {
        proxy_pass http://wordpress_english;
    }
}
```

**Problem:** Static files (css, js and images) are not loaded.

The output from the browser console shows a 404:

```
http://wordpress_english/wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen/genericons/genericons.css?ver=3.2
```

Its easy to spot the problem: The browser looks for the static files at wordpress_english (the nginx upstream name), instead of `my_domain.com`

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 5):

This is not a `nginx` problem, but a WordPress problem.

**Solution**:

In `wp-config.php`, add the following two lines:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://my_domain.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://my_domain.com');
```

> During the WordPress installation, WordPress automatically sets `WP_HOME` to `nginx` upstream name. The above solution overwrites the default setting.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be an issue in your nginx config file.

When declaring your server `my_domain` you provide `location /` with `proxy_pass wordpress_english`. I don't know a lot on nginx, but I don't see any declaration of path in your server `my_domain` and is root is linked to `wordpress_english`. Seems normal that he is looking for files in `wordpress_english` and not in you server. (In fact, I guess he is looking in your server but your server tells to look in wordpress).

Not sure about it cause I don't know well nginx and proxy_pass functions.